# cellForRowAtIndexPath not being called after successful api call

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

In my app(Using Storyboards FYI) I have a viewController which contains a tableView. My viewController hits an API and returns an array of items that my tableView should populate with. The problem is, after successfully retrieving the array, the reloadData method does not trigger a call to cellForRowAtIndexPath. I've set the delegate and datasource properly, and still have no luck. Here is my code:

in my viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc]init];
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;

    [[CCHTTPClient sharedClient] getItemsWithSuccess:^(NSArray *items) {

        self.items = items;
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(NSError *error) {
    }];
}
```

and also in my numberOfRowsInSection:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.items count];
}
```

I've also found that if i did an API call on the previous VC and set the array of the viewController's items before the viewController is pushed, the table populates properly. really unsure about what's going on here. Any help would be gratefully appreciated !

Comment: Are you sure that `items` is not `nil` and contains at least one value? Also, be sure you call `reloadData` on the main thread.

Comment: @rmaddy yes, i've set breakpoints on both. `items` contains one value, right before the table is reloaded(on the first thread)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self.tableView should be an outlet if your controller and table view are made in a storyboard. You're creating a different table view in viewDidLoad with alloc init, so you're calling reloadData on that one, not the one you have on screen. Remove that alloc init line, and connect the outlet in IB.

Comment: GAH. how dumb of me, thank you so much for figuring that out.I had the outlet connected in IB, so re-initializing it was causing the mistake. thank you so much!

Comment: I think the moral of the story is don't use SB.

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect this is caused by calling `reloadData` from a secondary thread. Try this:

```
[[AGHTTPClient sharedClient] getItemsWithSuccess:^(NSArray *items) {
    self.items = items;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
} failure:nil];
```

Comment: Good answer, UI updates are forbidden from background threads.  The dispatch wrapper ensures the reload is on the main thread OP.

Comment: thanks for the answer, although unfortunately i forgot to note that i tried this and it didn't work. any other ideas?

Comment: @User3294729579346597634 Other ideas? Yes, see my comment below the question.